# Plotting x axis HH:mm:SS for POSIXct

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code below is not being coverted to new york time. Any idea why? I see that it works in the posted answer but that code on my machine doe snot change the time.

```
 time = as.POSIXct(c("2016-06-30 15:20:23 GMT","2016-06-30 15:20:25 GMT","2016-06-30 15:20:27 GMT"),tz = "GMT")
 attr(time, "tzone") <- "America/New_York"
 #time = as.POSIXct(format(time, tz="America/New_York"),tz ="America/New_York")
 class(time)
 value = c(10,11,12)
     category = c(0,1,0)
     dat = data.frame(time = time, value = value, category = category)
     dat
                 time value category
1 2016-06-30 11:20:23    10        0
2 2016-06-30 11:20:25    11        1
3 2016-06-30 11:20:27    12        0
```

dat shows 11 as the hour but the plot below still shows the hour being 15?

```
 str(dat)
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(dat, aes(x=time, y = value, group = 1 )) +
   geom_point(aes (color = as.factor(category)) ) +geom_line()  + scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M:%S")
```

It wasn't converting to NY time because the scales package was out of date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the timezone, use the `tz =` argument to `as.POSIXct()`. Your input is in `"GMT"` so we can tell `R` that's the case. To convert to another timezone, set the attribute `tzone` appropriately.

To scale the x-axis as date/time, use `scale_x_datetime()` with appropriate format codes.

```r
time = as.POSIXct(c("2016-06-30 15:20:23 GMT",
                    "2016-06-30 15:20:25 GMT",
                    "2016-06-30 15:20:27 GMT"), tz = "GMT")
attr(time, "tzone") <- "America/New_York"

value = c(10,11,12)
category = c(0,1,0)
dat = data.frame(time = time, value = value, category = category)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = time, y = value, group = 1)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(category))) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H:%M:%S %Z")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer but that axis labelling in the first example is crazy. Number 2 seems like the go.

Comment: yep, I forgot that it was all single-day data. Output produced via `reprex()` so didn't have too much preview on how shrunk the scaling was. Updated to the actual answer now.

Comment: When I do as.POSIXct(c("2016-06-30 15:20:23 GMT","2016-06-30 15:20:25 GMT","2016-06-30 15:20:27 GMT"), tz = "America/New_York")  it adds 4 hours but it should be subtracting hours as new york is behind GMT.  I want to take GMT times and get the time in New york which will always be less than the GMT times

Comment: I think you have to use         format(time, tz="America/New_York")

Comment: Please see the editied code it is not converting to EST

Comment: Please don't change your question to include the answer, it makes it unclear what you originally asked. My answer is produced reproducibly - start with a clean session and run it again before you are sure it's not working.

Comment: I started a new instance and it still shows the hour being 15

Comment: I've put all the code back in - run just my answer in a clean, empty session. Did you clear out your variables?

Comment: Yes I cleared all variables and still get a 15 hour time on the x axis even though the dat$time shows 11 hour.  I think it is related to this issue from 4 years ago but i don't see a solution https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/533.  Is there a way to do this without scale_x_datetime?

Comment: I'm using `ggplot2_2.2.1` -- how old is your version?

Comment: Awesome yes I needed to update scales package. Thank you